# Converting Vector2Int to Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following situation in my game:

I have a matrix 6x6 and I store the player's position in a `Vector2Int`, as you can see in the image.
[image: Game board]

And when he is hit by a bullet, I'd to instantiate on his left, right, behind and front a gameobject. However I can't use a `Vector2Int` to do it, I've already tried to do this, but I got an error message:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Player2")
        {
            player.Health += Healing;

            Instantiate(Flame, player.GridPosition.y+1, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(Flame, player.GridPosition.y -1, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(Flame, player.GridPosition.x + 1, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(Flame, player.GridPosition.x - 1, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);

        }
    }
```

Is there a way that I could convert this `Vector2Int` into a `Vector3`?

Comment: player.GridPosition.y+1 is not even a vector2int but an int though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a new Vector3 using the values from your Vector2:

```
float defaultZValue;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Player2")
    {
        player.Health += Healing;

        Instantiate(Flame, new Vector3(player.GridPosition.x, player.GridPosition.y+1, defaultZValue), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(Flame, new Vector3(player.GridPosition.x, player.GridPosition.y-1, defaultZValue), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(Flame, new Vector3(player.GridPosition.x+1, player.GridPosition.y, defaultZValue), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(Flame, new Vector3(player.GridPosition.x-1, player.GridPosition.y, defaultZValue), Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

    }
}
```

---

As I understand your z position will not be changing, so you can use the same value for each `instantiate`, you can define it in your class. Also you may want to create another method for the instantiate process to make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Well `Vector3` has a constructor that takes two floats and initializes the other one to zero. `Vector2Int` has two properties `.x` and `.y` representing the x and y parts of the vector.

Combining these we get `Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(player.GridPosition.x, player.GridPosition.y)` as a Vector3 with the same x and y components as the Vector2Int.

Now whether this will behave as you expect is another matter as you are converting between your own custom coordinate system and Unity's, you may have to scale by the size of your grid if it is not 1x1 Unity units per tile.

Edit: as y is up in Unity, what you probably want is `Vector3(player.GridPosition.x, 0, player.GridPosition.y)` so that the grid y position becomes the world z position.

Comment: For OP, the y of his vector is probably Z axis, not Y

Comment: Have added an edit to clarify which direction Y points in unity.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the [Unity Grid component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html), which includes helper functions to translate between grid and world coordinates, as well as for translation between xyz, xzy and other grid layouts.

From Vector2Int to Vector3 you get by firs converting Vector2Int to Vector2 and then Unity will implicitly convert Vector2 to Vector3 for you.